# Android, Can we have repeated ids in different xml file for views?

Tags: android, user-interface

Assume that we have 3 different activities. Each activity has its own XML file for drawing UI.
In each XML file we have a TextView (but style of each one is different with the others).

I want to know what will happen if i assign same id to each of them for example `android:id = "@+id/textView"` for all of them.

Comment: yes. you can. findviewbyid method will return the textview from current layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);**
the **findViewById()** will get the textview from that particular layout only...so you can assign same ids in different activities..